# jQuery Validation - Using multiple errorLabelContainer

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, jquery-validate

I have a form with four different fieldsets.  For jQuery validation, I would like the errors from the inputs in each of the fieldsets to be placed in an error block at the top of the specific fieldset.  For example:

```
<fieldset id="contact">
  <legend>Contact Information</fieldset>
  <ul id="errors_contact" class="messages"></ul>
  <!-- input elements -->
</fieldset>

<fieldset id="financial">
    <legend>Financial Information</legend>
    <ul id="errors_financial" class="messages"></ul>
    <!-- input elements -->
</fieldset>
```

Can this be done with jQuery validation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It can't using `errorLabelContainer` specifically, there's one setting/store for `errorLabelContainer` in the code, *but* you can use [the `errorPlacement` and `wrapper` options](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions) for the *effect* you want, for example:

```
$("form").validate({
  wrapper: "li",
  errorPlacement: function(label, elem) {
    elem.closest("fieldset").find(".messages").append(label);
  }
});
```

Instead of the standard [`.insertAfter()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/) (normally placing the `<label>` after the element it goes with), this wraps it in a `<li></li>` and appends that to the `.messages` container for the current `<fieldset>`.

Comment: Thanks, I was part way there with this.  I am still getting the <label> tags in the error ie. <ul class="messages" id="errors_about"><li><label for="first_name" generated="true" class="error" style="display: block;">First name is required</label></li></ul>

Comment: @Matt - Usually you want then...so clicking the error takes you right to the element, do you *not* want this?

Comment: Oh right, of course.  My CSS on the page uses display: block for labels.  I will just change it to inline for .messages.

Comment: Actually, display: block is being set in the actual element but I could still adjust the CSS.

Comment: @Matt - You can change the `errorElement` if you want to something else, but I'd stick with `<label>` and fix the separate styling issue...does the `.error` class that's applied have `display: block;` in it?

Answer (score 1):

I did it this way:

I had a form that had to validate multiple controls - but I wanted one area of error - and one message for all - one line.

Default if you use errorLabelContainer it puts the validations as "add-ons" - that is multiple validations create many rows in the errorlabel.
I noticed one thing - if it had the height of labelcontainer less than 30px, it made a new empty row second time. I don't know why.

In my case it's a label - but it can be a div too, of course. In my HTML I have this (assuming you have the jQuery validation.js and base):

Myform is the name of the form - then the different HTML controls - any type - for example:

`INPUT id=theNameofcontrol type=checkbox name=theNameofcontrol validate=required:true`

Then the container for the error message (don't know how to make it look like HTML :)

`label id=errorlabel name=errorlabel style=font-size:1.3em;height:30;color:red; /label`

In my onclick function for the form, I put empty messages as errormessages and put a message if the form wasn't valid and return false if it isn't (so I don't post it.)

Of course you can just fill in every custom message - but I wanted to have one line regardless of how many errors.

```
$("#MyForm").validate(<br>
{<br>
errorLabelContainer:"#errorlabel",<br>
messages : <br>
    {theNameofcontrol: {required: "" },<br>
    theNameofcontrol2: {required: "" },<br>
    theNameofcontrol3: {required: "" }<br>
    }   <br>
);<br>
<br>
 if(! $("#MyForm").valid())<br>
{<br>
$("#errorlabel").html("My message when not all contols are valid!");<br>
return false;<br>
}
```

Hope this is helpful for you. You should be able to do the same for the fieldset if you have a container for all the "objects" in the group.

To validate one control you use:

```
$("#MyForm").validate({errorLabelContainer:"#errorlabel",messages :{theNameofcontrol: {required: "This has to have a value" }}}).element("#theNameofcontrol");
```

Good luck